# Read value of self-closing tag attribute in PHP with colon separated tagname

Tags: xml

First post.

Having problems with reading the "file" attribute value in self-closing tag format, example 
**<foo:bar file="text.file" />**.

I can read all the other attribute values in the RSS document in closed tags.

Using the following demo code in reading/updating the attributes "file" value, without success for self-closing tag.

```
$obj = new DOMDocument();
$obj->load('List.rss');
$i = 0;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($obj);
foreach($xpath->query("//*[name()='foo:bar']") as $attrib)
{
if ($i == 1) { //location of the "foo:bar" value to manipulate..
    echo $attrib->nodeName; //prints foo:bar OK
    echo $attrib->nodeValue; //prints empty string
    $attrib->nodeValue = '?yes'; //attempt to update attribute value
}
$i++;
}
```

The $attrib->nodeValue = '?yes'; assignment updates the node with **<foo:bar file="text.file" />?yes</foo:bar >**, not compatible with the required RSS format.

What I need is to update **<foo:bar file="text.file" />** with **<foo:bar file="text.file?yes" />**, basically adding a querystring on-the-fly without adding closing tags.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo:bar` means here is a namespace definition for the prefix `foo`. Look for an `xmlns:foo` attribute in the element node or is nearest ancestor.

The DOMNode::$nodeName is not the "real" name of the node. This is stored in two properties.
`DOMNode::$localName` is the name with out the prefix (`bar` in the example). `DOMNode::$namespaceURI` contains the namespace (The value from the `xmlns:foo` attribute).

To fetch namespaced nodes, you register it with your own prefix on the DOMXPath instance.

```
$xml = '<foo:bar xmlns:foo="urn:foo" file="text.file" />';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('f', 'urn:foo');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//f:bar') as $node) {
  $node->setAttribute('file', $node->getAttribute('file').'?query');
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:bar xmlns:foo="urn:foo" file="text.file?query"/>
```